# Can a maximal ideal of $k[x, y] / (f)$ be embedded as a maximal ideal of $k'[x, y] / (f)$ where $k'$ is the algebraic closure of $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let be $k$ some field, where I have $J$ maximal ideal of $k[x, y] / (f)$ for some $f \in k[x, y]$.

I want to know if it's possible for $J$ to be embedded as a maximal ideal of $k'[x, y] / (f)$.

For the context, I have some affine curve $K$ and I'm looking at the map $P = (a, b) \mapsto (x - a, y - b)$, this map is injective, but in the case where the field is algebraically closed, it becomes bijective.

I already know that (weak) Nullenstellensatz gives me some interesting results between maximal ideals and points of a curve, but it only works for algebraically closed fields. So I'm struggling and don't know if I miss (or misunderstood) something

Comment: What do you mean by embedded? For instance, the maximal ideal $(x^2 + 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ factors into $2$ maximal ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x]$, namely $(x - i)$ and $(x+i)$.

Comment: What do you mean "embedded"? For instance, there are ideals where one can pick the same generating set over $k'$, but there are no ideals so that the image of the ideal under the natural map $k[x,y]/(f)\to k'[x,y]/(f)$ induced from $k\to k'$ is a maximal ideal (assuming $k\neq k'$).

Comment: To make things more precise, i was discussing with Raito the proof of a theorem in algebraic geometry, namely that there is a one-to-one correspond between $Spm(\Gamma(K))$ and $K(\bar{k})$ for an affine curve K in $A_{k}^{2}$. I know that the map which sends a point $(a,b) \in \Gamma(K)$ to the maximal ideal $(x-a,y-b) \in Spm(\Gamma(K))$ is always injective and is a bijection when k = \bar{k}. I feel that the theorem we're looking for can be deduced from this one, and that is why I was trying to see how to naturaly associate a point in $\Gamma(\bar{k})$ to an ideal $m \in Spm(\Gamma(K))$.

Comment: To that extent, I wanted to find a way to find an ideal m' of $\Gamma(K)$ and take a maximal ideal that it could contain naturally.

Comment: Indeed, ideally, we would like to send $\textrm{Spm}(\Gamma(K))$ to $K(\bar{k})$

Comment: This information and the explanation of what you mean by "embed" should be in your original post - you ought to [edit] it in. As far as what you want, you can't do this, as the example of Richard D. James shows with one maximal ideal factoring in to a product of two maximal ideals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $J$ be a maximal ideal of $k[x,y]$ containing $f$,

- The main point is that $k[x,y]/J$ is algebraic over $k$. This is because neither $k(t)$ nor $k(t,s)$ nor their finite extensions are finitely generated as a $k$-algebra.
- Thus $J = (g(x),h(x,y))$ where $g(x)\in k[x]$ is non-zero irreducible and $h(x,y)\in k[x]/(g(x))[y]$ is non-zero irreducible.
- The maximal ideals of $\overline{k}[x,y]$ containing $J$ are those of the form $(x-a,y-b)$ where $a\in \overline{k}$ is a root of $g(x)\in k[x]$ and $b\in \overline{k}$ is a root of $h(a,y)\in k(a)[y]$. If $k$ has characteristic $0$ then there are $\deg(g)\deg(h) = [k[x,y]/J:k]$ of them and $\overline{k}[x,y]/J\cong \overline{k}^{[k[x,y]/J:k]}$